# In ctypes, when I use byref or pointer?

Tags: python

I'm using a proprietary library with ctypes. I know the name and signature of each function in that library.

But I have a doubt. How do I know if I use "byref" or "pointer"

I have no experience, so I appreciate the wealth of detail.

Some examples of functions:

```
rInfoEstendida1_ECF_Daruma(char *pszInfo1) 
rLerArqRegistroPAF_ECF_Daruma(char *pszCaminho, char *pszChave, char *pszReturn)
```

Thank.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you perhaps give some example signatures? A pointer is a variable which holds the _memory address_ of another variable. `byref` relates to when a method is called. byref means pass a reference to the original object (so if the method makes changes to the object, the calling method sees the changes), whereas byval means copy the value stored in that variable and pass that copy to the method. Sorry it's quite wordy but it's a big topic. (by _reference_ as opposed to by _value_)

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

It [`byref`] behaves similar to `pointer(obj)`, but the construction is a lot faster."

So I think you should use `byref`.